# Toggle class only on one element, react js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I`m changing class after clicking and it works. 
The problem is that, classes change simultaneously in both elements and not in each one separately. Maybe someone could look what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be useful.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class PageContentSupportFaq extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isExpanded: false
    };
  }

  handleToggle(e) {
    this.setState({
      isExpanded: !this.state.isExpanded
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { isExpanded } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="section__support--faq section__full--gray position-relative">
        <div className="container section__faq">
          <p className="p--thin text-left">FAQ</p>
          <h2 className="section__faq--title overflow-hidden pb-4">Title</h2>
          <p className="mb-5">Subtitle</p>
          <div className="faq__columns">
            <div
              onClick={e => this.handleToggle(e)}
              className={isExpanded ? "active" : "dummy-class"}
            >
              <p className="mb-0">
                <strong>First</strong>
              </p>
            </div>

            <div
              onClick={e => this.handleToggle(e)}
              className={isExpanded ? "active" : "dummy-class"}
            >
              <p className="mb-0">
                <strong>Second</strong>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PageContentSupportFaq;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every element must have its seperate expanded value. So we need an array in state.

And here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class PageContentSupportFaq extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { id: 1, name: "First", expanded: false },
      { id: 2, name: "Second", expanded: true },
      { id: 3, name: "Third", expanded: false }
    ]
  };

  handleToggle = id => {
    const updatedItems = this.state.items.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          expanded: !item.expanded
        };
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      items: updatedItems
    });
  };

  render() {
    return this.state.items.map(el => (
      <div
        key={el.id}
        onClick={() => this.handleToggle(el.id)}
        className={el.expanded ? "active" : "dummy-class"}
      >
        <p className="mb-0">
          <strong>{el.name}</strong>
          <span> {el.expanded.toString()}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    ));
  }
}

export default PageContentSupportFaq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get two state  one state for first and another  for a second and handle using two function like this

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class PageContentSupportFaq extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          isExpanded: false,
          isExpanded2:false,
        }
      }

      handleToggle(e){
        this.setState({
          isExpanded: !this.state.isExpanded
        })
      }
     handleToggle2(e){
        this.setState({
          isExpanded2: !this.state.isExpanded2
        })
      }

      render() {
        const {isExpanded,isExpanded2} = this.state;
        return (
          <div className="section__support--faq section__full--gray position-relative">


            <div className="container section__faq">
              <p className="p--thin text-left">FAQ</p>
              <h2 className="section__faq--title overflow-hidden pb-4">Title</h2>
              <p className="mb-5">Subtitle</p>
              <div className="faq__columns">

                <div onClick={(e) => this.handleToggle(e)} className={isExpanded ? "active" : "dummy-class"}>
                  <p className="mb-0"><strong>First</strong></p>
                </div>

                <div onClick={(e) => this.handleToggle2(e)} className={isExpanded2 ? "active" : "dummy-class"}>
                  <p className="mb-0"><strong>Second</strong></p>
                </div>


              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        );
      }

    }

    export default PageContentSupportFaq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to track toggled classes in array, that way it will support arbitrary number of components:

```
// Save elements data into array for easier rendering
const elements = [{ id: 1, name: "First" }, { id: 2, name: "Second" }];

class PageContentSupportFaq extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded: []
    };
  }

  handleToggle(id) {
    this.setState(state => {
      if (state.isExpanded.includes(id)) {
        return state.isExpanded.filter(elId => elId !== id);
      }
      return [...state.expanded, id];
    });
  }

  render() {
    return elements.map(el => (
      <div
        key={el.id}
        onClick={() => this.handleToggle(el.id)}
        className={this.isExpanded(el.id) ? "active" : "dummy-class"}
      >
        <p className="mb-0">
          <strong>{el.name}</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    ));
  }
}
```